# Devise: cannot sign in (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've installed Rails 3.2.13 with Devise 2.2.4. I've used default Devise settings (except config.mail_sender), converted views from erb to slim and nothing more. Now i have strange bug: user can register, can restore password, but cannot sign in!

Logs:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 188.186.102.147 at 2013-07-14 17:58:42 +0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eqZ9zAUWn+blmhNMTi3iqhjX9ac1N8EaXpqNMyp/fYw=", "user"=>{"email"=>"ertaquo@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Войти"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eqZ9zAUWn+blmhNMTi3iqhjX9ac1N8EaXpqNMyp/fYw=", "user"=>{"email"=>"ertaquo@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Войти"}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.slim (3.8ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/application (59.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 208ms (Views: 83.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "robot@nizarium.com"

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Dump of users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `encrypted_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `reset_password_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_password_sent_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sign_in_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `current_sign_in_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_sign_in_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_sign_in_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_sign_in_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_reset_password_token` (`reset_password_token`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'ertaquo@gmail.com','$2a$10$tLC/NVBIa3cyI0HkiaZ7O.oXKTZ/jVm/L8jDMsSQ27CzNWcefWkCm',NULL,NULL,NULL,2,'2013-07-14 15:49:29','2013-07-14 12:37:07','188.186.102.147','188.186.102.147','2013-07-14 12:37:07','2013-07-14 15:49:29');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: 401 error usually indicates that the required authentication has failed or has not been provided: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes</a>

Comment: You either provided wrong login(email) or password. Do you have any users created? What does flash message say?

Comment: I have one user (myself) and i use correct login and password (tried even copy-paste). Flash message told about incorrect username or password.

Comment: @ertaquo don't want to copy and paste because it may include white space

Comment: Anyway, password is correct. I created and re-created account several times, i typed this password many times. Problem is not in incorrect password, really.

Answer (score 8):

Ok so I have solved this for my issue. Was my mistake in the first place aswell. A couple of things

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

I had removed these lines from my sessions/new view in layouts when I tried to build my own login form. So when I was inserting the admin and password from my rake task when I install my app, I wasn't getting the indication that the account hadn't been confirmed or that the password, username was incorrect.

Once I added those lines, thanks to the [solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005500/always-getting-401-unauthorized-with-new-install-of-rails-devise?rq=1) I was able to see that I was using the wrong email address because I'm a bloody noob.

Comment: These two lines are not part of the solution, but one certainly debugs it faster!  It is really hard to do without.

Answer (score -8):

Solved: i've installed Rails 4 with Devise, there is no such problem.

Comment: I have Rails 4 with devise and still have this issue...Ill post back if I solve it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11473726)

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Mind explaining to me how this doesn't attempt to provide an answer?

Comment: @Undo, it seems a very poor attempt at an answer as there are hardly any details to explain the issue and the solution.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous It might be poor, sure. You should downvote and comment on poor answers. Deletion is reserved for link-only answers and non-answers. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664) for guidance on what should and shouldn't be deleted from review.