# Typus with existing devise model getting 401 unauthorized error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, typus

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I have a problem configuring typus with devise.

I have an Rails REST app (built using rails_api) and it uses devise to do the authentication stuff. Currently I'm working on a new Rails app that supposed to be the admin pages of the REST app using typus. Ultimately, my aim is to have this admin app access the same database as the REST app that have been built before while using the existing devise model of the REST app. However, I keep getting 401 Unathorized message even though the user exists in the database.

To be precise, I have a devise model, `Account`, in the REST app and I want to use this particular devise model as the devise model in my admin app. I copied the model `Account` (alongside other models) from the REST app to the new admin app, then, I followed [this](http://typus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes/devise-authentication.html) to configure typus to use devise for authentication but without generating a new devise model:

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate typus

# config/initializers/typus.rb
Typus.setup do |config|
  config.authentication = :devise
  config.user_class_name = "Account"
end

# edit the devise model: Account
require 'typus/orm/active_record/instance_methods'
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable, :confirmable

  include Typus::Orm::ActiveRecord::InstanceMethods

  def locale
    ::I18n.locale
  end

  def role
    Typus.master_role
  end
end

# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :accounts
end

# initializers/devise.rb
# make secret_key the same with REST app's secret_key
config.secret_key = 'identic-secret-key-with-rest-app'
```

When I run the server and tried to sign in using the existing user in the database (user from the REST app) it always keep saying 401 Unauthorized in the server console. Is there anything that I missed in my configuration? or even my approach is doable?

It worked well if I generate a new devise model for the admin app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005500/always-getting-401-unauthorized-with-new-install-of-rails-devise This might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding **:confirmable** in your account model when you signup it will send you the confirmation mail to confirm your email, if you login without confirming it will throw an Unauthorized error.

Comment: Thanks, this is really the problem, after filling the `confirmed_at` column the problem was solved.