# Devise & Ruby on Rails: How to resolve "Completed 401 Unauthorized" when trying to Log In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm trying to use the Devise gem (v4.7.2) with Ruby on Rails (v6.0.3.2).

I'm receiving the following output when I click on the Sign In button:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-11-21 18:02:54 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3tBTwyz4dIihzNvUllHVX1b9iOzVANtyceTYQY9vfn2mHdSfmG9ivEFapBiry7I8753OCP6MrMkIVckxSGTxnQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"johanhanlon@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 486)


Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3tBTwyz4dIihzNvUllHVX1b9iOzVANtyceTYQY9vfn2mHdSfmG9ivEFapBiry7I8753OCP6MrMkIVckxSGTxnQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"johanhanlon@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 191)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 15.9ms | Allocations: 602)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/nav/_public.html.erb (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 151)
Completed 200 OK in 347ms (Views: 90.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 21362)
```

"Completed 401 Unauthorized" is showing and I'm not sure how to resolve this. Here are my files:

config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Assuming you have not yet modified this file, each configuration option below
# is set to its default value. Note that some are commented out while others
# are not: uncommented lines are intended to protect your configuration from
# breaking changes in upgrades (i.e., in the event that future versions of
# Devise change the default values for those options).
#
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  # Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key`
  # by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
  # config.secret_key = '###'

  # ==> Controller configuration
  # Configure the parent class to the devise controllers.
  # config.parent_controller = 'DeviseController'

  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

  # Configure the parent class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [:email]
  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database authentication.
  # For API-only applications to support authentication "out-of-the-box", you will likely want to
  # enable this with :database unless you are using a custom strategy.
  # The supported strategies are:
  # :database      = Support basic authentication with authentication key + password
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If 401 status code should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. 'Application' by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # particular strategies by setting this option.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing skip: :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # By default, Devise cleans up the CSRF token on authentication to
  # avoid CSRF token fixation attacks. This means that, when using AJAX
  # requests for sign in and sign up, you need to get a new CSRF token
  # from the server. You can disable this option at your own risk.
  # config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true

  # When false, Devise will not attempt to reload routes on eager load.
  # This can reduce the time taken to boot the app but if your application
  # requires the Devise mappings to be loaded during boot time the application
  # won't boot properly.
  # config.reload_routes = true

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 12. If
  # using other algorithms, it sets how many times you want the password to be hashed.
  # The number of stretches used for generating the hashed password are stored
  # with the hashed password. This allows you to change the stretches without
  # invalidating existing passwords.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments. Note that, for bcrypt (the default
  # algorithm), the cost increases exponentially with the number of stretches (e.g.
  # a value of 20 is already extremely slow: approx. 60 seconds for 1 calculation).
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12

  # Set up a pepper to generate the hashed password.
  # config.pepper = '###'

  # Send a notification to the original email when the user's email is changed.
  # config.send_email_changed_notification = false

  # Send a notification email when the user's password is changed.
  # config.send_password_change_notification = false

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming their account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming their account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day.
  # You can also set it to nil, which will allow the user to access the website
  # without confirming their account.
  # Default is 0.days, meaning the user cannot access the website without
  # confirming their account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed, new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed_email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [:email]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # Invalidates all the remember me tokens when the user signs out.
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # secure: true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.rememberable_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  # config.unlock_keys = [:email]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
  # config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [:email]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # reset. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after a reset.
  # config.sign_in_after_reset_password = true

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another hashing or encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default).
  # You can use :sha1, :sha512 or algorithms from others authentication tools as
  # :clearance_sha1, :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20
  # for default behavior) and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set
  # stretches to 10, and copy REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper).
  #
  # Require the `devise-encryptable` gem when using anything other than bcrypt
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  # config.scoped_views = false

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: '/my_engine'
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using OmniAuth, Devise cannot automatically set OmniAuth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/my_engine/users/auth'

  # ==> Turbolinks configuration
  # If your app is using Turbolinks, Turbolinks::Controller needs to be included to make redirection work correctly:
  #
  # ActiveSupport.on_load(:devise_failure_app) do
  #   include Turbolinks::Controller
  # end

  # ==> Configuration for :registerable

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # changed. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after changing a password.
  # config.sign_in_after_change_password = true
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
  :validatable, :confirmable, authentication_keys: [:login]

  # Create relationship - User has many properties.
  has_many :properties

  attr_writer :login

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end

end
```

controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    protect_from_forgery prepend: true
    
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def index
    end

    protected

    # Restrict parameters for sign up input.
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_in, keys: added_attrs
    end

end
```

controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<section class="form-auth text-center">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <!-- <img class="mb-4" src="" alt="" width="72" height="72"> -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Log In</h1>

    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", id: "inputEmail", placeholder: "Email address", autocomplete: "current-email", required: "" %>

    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control", id: "inputPassword", required: "" %>
    
    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2020</p>

  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</section>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:email])` instead of `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])`?

Comment: The sessions_controller.rb file is the standard devise commented out code. I haven't done anything with this but just wanted to show it to be clearer about the question. I could be wrong but I don't think that this is the issue although you have got me thinking. I think I'm missing a sanitizer for sign_in - 'devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_in, keys: added_attrs'

Comment: Great, that's fixed the "Unpermitted parameter: :email" error but I still have the "Completed 401 Unauthorized" error. I'll update the question now.

Comment: Wild guess. Did you [confirm the email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14006820/5841310)?

Comment: Yes, I did this by clicking on the link in the terminal. I'll do another new registration to test this again and make sure.

Comment: First, it calls Devise::SessionsController#create which results in "Completed 401 Unauthorized". Then it calls Devise::SessionsController#new which results in "Completed 200 OK".

Comment: First should be GET to access the form and then POST to create session, right?

Comment: Did you solve it? I am experiencing the same thing and it's annoying.

Comment: @ccoeder Yes, this was resolved. I'm looking back at this and I'll post my working code today.

Comment: @ccoeder See answer below - if you're issue is the similar to mine, this should help. However if still not working for you please let me know in the comments and we will try to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this and my working code is below.

The main issue was that I was passing in an incorrect parameter in my configure_permitted_parameters function when sanitizing the parameters. I was passing in `:password` but this should have been `:encrypted_password`. See below.

```
# Restrict parameters for sign up input.
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :encrypted_password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: added_attrs)
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: added_attrs)
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: added_attrs)
    end
```

The parameter/attribute `:encrypted_password` being sanitized is shown below in the db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_devise_create_users.rb migration file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :first_name,         null: false, default: ""
      t.string :last_name,          null: false, default: ""
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :url

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Other files from the question are below for reference:

config/initializers/devise.rb below:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Assuming you have not yet modified this file, each configuration option below
# is set to its default value. Note that some are commented out while others
# are not: uncommented lines are intended to protect your configuration from
# breaking changes in upgrades (i.e., in the event that future versions of
# Devise change the default values for those options).
#
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  # Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key`
  # by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
  # config.secret_key = 'INSERT YOUR SECREY KEY HERE'

  # ==> Controller configuration
  # Configure the parent class to the devise controllers.
  # config.parent_controller = 'DeviseController'

  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

  # Configure the parent class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [:email]
  # config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database authentication.
  # For API-only applications to support authentication "out-of-the-box", you will likely want to
  # enable this with :database unless you are using a custom strategy.
  # The supported strategies are:
  # :database      = Support basic authentication with authentication key + password
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If 401 status code should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. 'Application' by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # particular strategies by setting this option.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing skip: :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # By default, Devise cleans up the CSRF token on authentication to
  # avoid CSRF token fixation attacks. This means that, when using AJAX
  # requests for sign in and sign up, you need to get a new CSRF token
  # from the server. You can disable this option at your own risk.
  # config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true

  # When false, Devise will not attempt to reload routes on eager load.
  # This can reduce the time taken to boot the app but if your application
  # requires the Devise mappings to be loaded during boot time the application
  # won't boot properly.
  # config.reload_routes = true

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 12. If
  # using other algorithms, it sets how many times you want the password to be hashed.
  # The number of stretches used for generating the hashed password are stored
  # with the hashed password. This allows you to change the stretches without
  # invalidating existing passwords.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments. Note that, for bcrypt (the default
  # algorithm), the cost increases exponentially with the number of stretches (e.g.
  # a value of 20 is already extremely slow: approx. 60 seconds for 1 calculation).
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12

  # Set up a pepper to generate the hashed password.
  # config.pepper = 'xxx'

  # Send a notification to the original email when the user's email is changed.
  # config.send_email_changed_notification = false

  # Send a notification email when the user's password is changed.
  # config.send_password_change_notification = false

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming their account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming their account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day.
  # You can also set it to nil, which will allow the user to access the website
  # without confirming their account.
  # Default is 0.days, meaning the user cannot access the website without
  # confirming their account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed, new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed_email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [:email]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # Invalidates all the remember me tokens when the user signs out.
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # secure: true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.rememberable_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  # config.unlock_keys = [:email]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
  # config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  # config.reset_password_keys = [:email]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # reset. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after a reset.
  # config.sign_in_after_reset_password = true

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another hashing or encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default).
  # You can use :sha1, :sha512 or algorithms from others authentication tools as
  # :clearance_sha1, :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20
  # for default behavior) and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set
  # stretches to 10, and copy REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper).
  #
  # Require the `devise-encryptable` gem when using anything other than bcrypt
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  # config.scoped_views = false

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: '/my_engine'
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using OmniAuth, Devise cannot automatically set OmniAuth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/my_engine/users/auth'

  # ==> Turbolinks configuration
  # If your app is using Turbolinks, Turbolinks::Controller needs to be included to make redirection work correctly:
  #
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:devise_failure_app) do
    include Turbolinks::Controller
  end

  # ==> Configuration for :registerable

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # changed. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after changing a password.
  # config.sign_in_after_change_password = true
end
```

models/user.rb below:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  # devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable, :confirmable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
  :validatable, :confirmable#, authentication_keys: [:login]

  # Create relationship - User has many properties.
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
  has_many :portfolios, dependent: :destroy

  # attr_writer :login

  # def login
  #   # @login || self.username || self.email
  #   @login || self.email || self.encrypted_password
  # end

  # def contact_name
  #   "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  # end

  # def company_name
  #   "AGENT"
  # end

end
```

controllers/application_controller.rb below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    # Store last page for redirecting to last page on log in or log out.
    before_action :store_user_location!, if: :storable_location?

    protect_from_forgery prepend: true
    
    # To enable sign in to function correctly.
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def index
        
    end

    protected

    # Restrict parameters for sign up input.
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :encrypted_password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: added_attrs)
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: added_attrs)
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: added_attrs)
    end

    private
    
    def storable_location?
        request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr? 
    end

    def store_user_location!
        # :user is the scope we are authenticating
        store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end

end
```

controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb below:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /users/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || super
  end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

views/devise/session/new.html.erb below:

```
<section class="form-auth text-center">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <!-- <img class="mb-4" src="" alt="" width="72" height="72"> -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Log In</h1>

    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", id: "inputEmail", placeholder: "Email address", autocomplete: "current-email", required: "" %>

    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control", id: "inputPassword", required: "" %>
    
    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2020</p>

  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</section>
```