# 401 Unauthorized when signing in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have been days trying to fix this problem and I am helpless at this point. I have read a lot of related SO posts but none of them work for me. I have this block of code in my `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :v1 do
  devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json }, controllers: { sessions: 'api/v1/sessions' }
end
```

And my sessions controller looks like this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    end
  end
end
```

When I do this request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/sign_in' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "user": {
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "password": "Test123!"
    }
}'
```

or this one:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/sign_in' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email": "cfo@test.com",
    "password": "Test123#"
}'
```

The credentials are right. I have doubled checked. But I get this message:

```
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

Why is it asking me to sign in to sign in? Doesn't make any sense to me. My application controller looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: %i[email password])
  end
```

Posts I have read without any successful result:

- [Always getting 401 Unauthorized with new install of Rails + Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005500/always-getting-401-unauthorized-with-new-install-of-rails-devise) (doesn't work because I am not rendering any HTML)
- [Devise & Ruby on Rails: How to resolve "Completed 401 Unauthorized" when trying to Log In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944363/devise-ruby-on-rails-how-to-resolve-completed-401-unauthorized-when-trying) (I changed `password` with `encrypted_password` and didn't work)

And probably more other posts outside SO but none of them worked. Also, is it possible that `Devise::SessionsController` goes through another file (not `application_controller.rb` but `base_controller.rb` which is inside my `api/v1/` folder and also inherits from `ActionController::Base`?)

Comment: Can you post the server logs immediately after the `curl` request?

Comment: Have you generated the Devise controller to be able to inspect or change the sign_in process? `rails generate devise:controllers`

Comment: I find this tutorial really helpful: https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/

Comment: Can you post your `rails routes` output?